# Selecting posts id's from Array of user id's - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, mysqli

I have an Array of id's I follow 
if I echo:

```
echo json_encode($followingIds);
```

prints:

```
[{"User_two_id":"3"},{"User_two_id":"4"},{"User_two_id":"5"}]
```

I now want to select All id's from Post table where the value/s of Author are equal to the value of my User_two_id's in my array.

"Author is indexing id's of user_two"

Here is where I've got so far which is not working

```
function getPosts( $follwingIds ) {

        $sql = "SELECT id
        FROM posts
        WHERE Author IN ('$follwingIds')
        GROUP BY id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Author)";

    $result = $this->conn->query( $sql );

    if ( $result != null ) {

        while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            $returnArray[] = $row;
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: Where does the array come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is here:

```
WHERE Author IN ('$follwingIds')
```

here `$follwingIds` in an `JSON object` where as mysql `IN` required value in comma separated values. So instead of making an json array convert it to string like:

```
$follwIds = implode(',', array_column($follwingIds, 'User_two_id'));
```

and use it in query like:

```
WHERE Author IN ($follwIds)
```

Comment: Thanks, however it returns null for some reason. like it never passes `if ( $result != null ) {` I echoed $follwIds and it looks fine (3,4,5), I even did a manual  query in phpmyadmin and placed WHERE Author IN (3,4,5) .. it gave what I wanted but it doesn't work in php for some reason!

Comment: Your function do not return any value may be that's the reason

Comment: thanks but shouldn't it still pass the if statement within the function? `if ( $result != null ) { echo "notnull"; ..`

Comment: You are saying that the execution do not entering in If part?

Comment: No it doesn't pass the if since $result is null by the look of it? is there something I'm missing in my query?

Comment: Check the connection settings and DB name

Comment: I changed my while loop and it's now working fine `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) $test[] = $row;`

Comment: That's great !!